# How to take screenshot in protractor on failure of test cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, protractor

I am new to the protractor and would like to take screenshots of my failed test cases in browsers.

Can you please help me out by advising how should I go about it?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use `protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter` module for this, it has some good features which would serve your purpose.

```
 var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');

 var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
 dest: 'target/screenshots',
 filename: 'my-report.html',
 captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true
});
```

This will capture screenshots when your specs have failed, you have many more options, you can checkout this link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter

Answer (score 6):

The code below can be placed within the exports.config block of **protractor.conf.js**:

```
const fs = require('fs');
. . . 
exports.config = {
. . . 
onPrepare: function() {
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
  specDone: function(result) {
    browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(screenShot) {

      //    Saving File.
      //    Param filePath : where you want to store screenShot
      //    Param screenShot : Screen shot file which you want to store. 

      fs.writeFile(filePath, screenShot, 'base64', function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('File saved.');
      });

    });
  }
});
}
```

I hope it helps! :)

[Reference link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1753#issuecomment-71541760)

Similarly, if you want it to only take screenshots on failures, you can place the call to takeScreenshot within a conditional matching a result.failedExpectations.length greater than 0:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
  specDone: (result) => {
    if(result.failedExpectations.length > 0) {
      browser.takeScreenshot().then((screenShot) => {
        fs.writeFile('./protractorFailure.png', screenShot, 'base64', (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

[protractor-beautiful-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-beautiful-reporter) is capable of building nice html reports including the screenshots.

Installation:

```
npm install protractor-beautiful-reporter --save-dev
```

Configuration in `protractor.conf.js`:

```
const HtmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');

exports.config = {
   // your config here ...

   onPrepare: function() {
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
         baseDirectory: 'target/screenshots',
         takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true
      }).getJasmine2Reporter());
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome thank you for this advice :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `framework: 'custom'` in protractor.conf.js then using Jasmine or a Jasmine reporter doesn't seem to work.

You can do something like the following in your post-test hook (e.g. cucumber.After):

```
  protractor.browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(screenshot) {
    const screenshots = path.join(process.cwd(), 'e2e/reports/screenshots');

    fs.writeFile(screenshots + '/test.png', screenshot, 'base64', function (err) {
      if (err) {
          throw err;
      }
      console.log('File saved.');
    });
  });
```

Comment: And to check if test case passed or not, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54367506/73010