# Is there a configuration in CucumberJS to take screenshot on Error?

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

using CucumberJS
Is there an option or configuration to capture screenshot on error after the execution of test?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [function to take screenshots for cucumber-html-reporter generates "function timed out after 5000.." error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423453/function-to-take-screenshots-for-cucumber-html-reporter-generates-function-time)

Answer (score 5):

You can take screenshot through cucumber `After` hook as following:

```
// supports/take-screenshot.js

var { After, Status } = require("cucumber");

After(function(testCase) {
    var me = this;

    if (testCase.result.status === Status.FAILED) {
        return browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(screenshot) {
            return me.attach(screenshot, "image/png");
        });
    }
});
```

Then include above hook file into `cucumberOpts.requires` in protractor conf.js as below:

```
// cucumberOpts in protractor conf.js
cucumberOpts: {

    require: [
       "supports/cucumber-screenshot.js", 
       "steps/**/*step.js"
    ]
 }
```